# Modify React.js class -- override methods?

Tags: reactjs

I've create a component with React.js
`var A = React.createClass({ abc: function () {} })`
How can i access `abc` method? A.prototype.abc is undefined

Comment: See the React docs for how to [communicate between components](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html). In particular, "For communication between two components that don't have a parent-child relationship, you can set up your own global event system."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All methods on React components should be considered private.  There are very rare exceptions.  The public api of the component is the props it takes.

Comment: for example its a helper method to format string. its okay to put it in props?

Comment: Sure, you can pass anything you like as props.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to store methods in plain js object and to add method `toReact`. Exmaple:

```
var Game = {
 render: function () {
    return (
      <PlayersTable data={ this.props.data } />
    )
  },

  toReact: function () {
    return React.createClass(this)
  }
}
```